# SAS define a macro inside a data step

Tags: sas

I have some legacy SAS code that defines a macro inside a data step. How does this work? Does the macro get compiled for every iteration of DATA step?

```
    data test;
    set temp;
    %macro cal_sum(iput);
    %let a=&input.;
    %mend;
    REPORTING_DATE = &PROCDATE.;
    call execute('%cal_sum(testval)');
    run;
```

Comment: The code as posted is just defining a macro and there is no call to execute it.  The macro will be defined while SAS is reading the code and before it starts running the data step.  So it would be the same if the macro code was moved to before the `data` statement.   What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I edited the code. I want the macro to execute for each data step iteration ,calculate a variable and add it to the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  In this case, the macro is compiled before the data step executes.  There are only three ways you can run / compile a macro for every iteration of a data step:

1. `dosubl()`
2. `run_macro` within an `fcmp` call
3. `call execute` - but note that any generated SAS code is executed AFTER the data step.

The way it works is:

`data test; set temp;` is sent to the stack, ready to be executed on the next step boundary

`%macro cal_sum(iput);%mend;` macro is compiled (not executed)

`REPORTING_DATE = &PROCDATE.;run;` is sent to the stack, and executed (as the `run;` statement is a step boundary)

Answer (score 1):

The macro code, in this case a macro definition, gets fully resolved before the data step is compiled and run by the SAS executor.

So no, the macro is not compiled for every iteration of the DATA step.

Also, as you my be aware, a macro call coded inside a data step is not invoked for every iteration, however, whatever source code the macro call emitted will be.

Comment: Thanks. Basically what I want is the macro to assign a particular value to a variable that will become part of the dataset 'test'. How can I do this?

Comment: A macro `call execute`d can not add a variable to the pdv.  A macro `call execute`d can perform a macro-symbol only computation and assign the result to a macro variable whose value can be obtained in a running DATA step using `symget()` or `symgetn()`.  Macro variables are really 'symbols` in a symbol table, and represent an associated value that is introduced into the token parsing stream via &.

Comment: I think you are over complicating your solution.  Is the macro computing something that data step statements can't ?  Try to write plain-sas data step no-macro version first, and ask questions about that before jumping to macro

Comment: i need three additional variables..the variable names are dynamic, following a pattern...the macro computes the variable names and assigns them a value...without it, i have to explicitly define the variable names in DATA step...i.e var_test;var_train;var_validate...

Comment: For this kind of question it is best to show a `have` data set, and a `want` data set, show tried code and explain the transformation if it is not obvious.  When the values of a variable drive a desired column name the process is generally one of transposition or tabular reporting.